# Manipulating Documents with Collection2 and Collection-helpers

Tags: meteor, meteorite

So I'm not sure where this issue comes down to but here's what's going on.

I have a collection, say `Items`. I have a `name` attribute and a collection-helper `count`.

When I fetch some items, `Items.find().fetch()`, I notices I get back an array of `Document.(anonymous function)`. Not sure if this is a matter `collection2` or `collection-helpers` but it makes sense because I'm doing a lot of funny business with my collections.

Anyways, I want to pick off some values from what was returned

```
items = Items.find().fetch().map(function(a) { return _.pick(a, "name", "_id", "count") })
```

And that doesnt work. If I leave out `count`, then it works and returns an object, so I suspect this is an issue with `collection-helpers`. Any ideas how to solve this issue? Any other advice about whats going on with `Document.(anonymous function)` -- I've never seen that before.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're not picking out a field that your `count` helper might need to reference. Can you post the code for that helper?

`Document.(anonymous function)` is just the way that Chrome/webkit represents what's returned from how collection-helpers goes about applying the transform to collections.